# Why isn't the ls command listing huge filesizes?

Tags: linux, centos, ls

In my Redhat Linux, I am getting the following error when executing the `ls` command.

```
# ls
ls: sugar.sql: Value too large for defined data type
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type -

> It means that your version of the utilities were not compiled with large file support enabled. The GNU utilities do support large files if they are compiled to do so. You may want to compile them again and make sure that large file support is enabled. ...